# Logarithm Subtraction

Tags: calculus, economics

When I read a textbook of Econometrics, there is derivation about logarithm: $log(x_1) - log(x_0)$ approximately equals to $\frac{(x_1-x_0)} {x_0 }= \frac{\delta x}{x_0}$ . The text noted that you need to use calculus. Could someone can tell how is the result derived? Thank you!

Comment: What exacly is $x_0$?

Comment: Sorry, a typo. It has been corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider the case where positive $\ x\ y\ $ are such that $\ y-x\ $ is relatively small when compared to $\ x,\ $ which means that $\ \frac{y-x}x\ $ is small. Then

$$ \log(y)-\log(x)\ =\ \log(\frac yx)\ =
\ \log\big(1+\frac{y-x}x\big) $$

However, and it's a classic, $\ \log(1+\epsilon)\ $ is approximately equal $\ \epsilon\ $ when $\ \epsilon\ $ is
small. We may consider $\ \frac{y-x}x\ $ to be a small $\ \epsilon.\ $ Then indeed,
$\ \log(y)-\log(x),\ $ i.e.
$\ \log\big(1+\frac{y-x}x\big),\ $ is approximetely

$$ \frac {y-x}x\ =\ \frac{\Delta x}x $$

*(Hey, how nice!)*

> **EXTRA:**

$$ \forall_{\epsilon>-1}\quad \log(1+\epsilon)\ =
    \ \int_{x=0}^\epsilon\frac {dx}{1+x} $$

Thus, looking at the area under the hyperbole $\ \frac 1{1+\epsilon}\ $ and the respective rectangles, we get

$$ \frac\epsilon{1+\epsilon}\,\ \le\,\ \log(1+\epsilon)
      \,\ \le\,\ \epsilon $$
We get even a sharper inequality by looking at the respective trapezoids:

$$ \frac{2+3\cdot\epsilon}{2+2\cdot\epsilon}\cdot\frac\epsilon{1+\epsilon}
\,\ \le\,\ \log(1+\epsilon)
     \,\ \le\,\ \frac{2+\epsilon}{2+2\cdot\epsilon}\cdot\epsilon $$

> **REMARK:** When $\ -1<\epsilon<0,\ $ you have to concentrate on the above inequalities a bit harder to untangle the negative signs -- the inequalities still hold as written, no big deal.

Comment: You beat me by 5 seconds. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, I am not a fighter, I am a (math) lover.

Comment: I am sure you are, as well as I am !

Comment: Thank you @WlodAA! one more question: Can I got much information on this statement " it's a classic,  log(1+ϵ)  is approximately equal  ϵ  when  ϵ  is small" ? This definition is in calculus textbook or other math books ?

Comment: @Steve, I have fulfilled your request before I saw it (I was busy writing it :) ).

Comment: Sharper inequalities are still possible, **of course**, but it'd be harder to incorporate them here (more cumbersome).

Comment: So you are using Taylor series to prove an inequality, right ?

Comment: One could use the Taylor series. Here, I am using the equation: $\ \log(x)=\int_1^x\frac{dt}t\ $ (arguably, this is the best definition of the real logarithm, and it allows a similar one for the complex case).

Comment: (I am very poor when it comes to references, I am sorry).

Comment: Got it ! Thank you for your help~